# Motivation for the definition of the projective line over a ring

Tags: ring-theory, projective-geometry, inversive-geometry

Given a ring (with identity) R, the definition for the projective line over a ring I have is as follows:

On $R \times R$ define an equivalence relation as $(u, v) \sim (a, b)$ if and only if there is some unit $r \in R$ such that $(r a, r b) = (u, v)$.

Two elements $a, b \in R$ are relatively prime if the ideal in $R$ that they generate is the whole of $R$; that is, $R a + R b = R$. The projective line over R is the set of equivalence classes for $\sim$ on pairs of relatively prime elements:

$$P(R) = \{(a,b) \in R \times R : R a + R b = R \}/{\sim}.$$

Comparing the definition with the definition for projective lines over fields, I see that we would want to restrict the multipliers $r$ to be units so that $\sim$ is symmetric. My question is, why do we want to restrict the entries in pairs $(a,b)$ to be relatively prime? Is there perhaps some particular ring $R$ that sheds light on this, that is, where it's clear for some reason that we should only consider relatively prime pairs?

Comment: I would like to ask: where did you learn about this?

Comment: @rschwieb I'm currently doing some research involving hyperbolic 3-space whose boundary can be identified with the complex projective line; I wanted to generalise certain results to rings which led me to consider projective lines over rings. The actual definition I've given here can be found on the Wikipedia page for Inversive Ring Geometry, which according to that page is all about generalising projective concepts to rings, but I haven't had the chance to study it in much detail yet.

Comment: OK, I suspected you found it on the Wikipedia page, because that is the original source of the phrase "inversive ring geometry." There isn't really a field of mathematics with that name (to speak of), but the concepts do come out of "inversive geometry," so I think if you swapped for that tag, you might get more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are equivalent:

- $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime elements of $R$
- $(f(a), f(b)) \neq (0,0)$ for every homomorphism $f : R \to F$ to a field $F$

Incidentally, if $R$ is a field, then the only pair of elements that is not relatively prime is $(0,0)$.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't feel completely satisfied just yet, but this certainly helps, thanks.

Comment: The ability to map $P(R) \to P(S)$ given a ring homomorphism $R \to S$ is important, I think. Anyways, you might also be interested in [wheels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory). Wheels can, for example, have $1/2$ and $2/4$ be different elements. In the example I have in mind, $2/4$ can be given the interpretation as something that is undefined modulo 2, but meaningful (and the same as $1/2$) modulo any other prime.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if $R=\mathbb{Z}$, then you don't want to consider (2,4) as a point because (1,2) is already the "same" point.  In the case of a domain, you could get around this by defining an equivalence on all non-zero pairs as $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ iff $ad=bc$, but this won't work in a non-domain (it won't be transitive).  I guess excluding non-relatively prime pairs is the best you can do for a general ring $R$.

Comment: If you use that method to "get around this", you are simply constructing $P(Q)$, where $Q$ is the fraction field of $R$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had actually thought of what you pointed out (in the general context of a PID) that if there is a common non-unit divisor it would be identified with a relatively prime pair anyway but then I didn't see any reason to exclude the non relatively prime pairs just on this basis.

Answer (score 0):

We can also interpret your equivalence relation as considering the orbit space of a group action: $R^\times$ acts on $R\times R$ by $u(x,y):=(ux,uy)$, then the orbits are precisely your equivalence classes.

Now, for the orbit space to be smooth, we need the action to be free. It turns out, if $Rx+Ry=R$, say $ax+by=1$ and $u$ stabilising $(x,y)$, we have $1=ax+by=aux+buy=u$, so that $(x,y)$ has trivial stabiliser. Of course, if $R$ is an integral domain, all stabilisers are trivial, so this is not the whole explanation, but I found it a helpful intuition.